# call methods of type parameter from methods of templated class (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, hashmap

I'm trying to implement HashMap in C++ using templates ( and at the same time learn how templates work ). To do so I need to call method `T :: equals()` from parameter type `T`.

This is simplified code of what I need:

```
template < class T > class Map{
    public:
    T* [] cells;
    replaceIfEquals( int index,  T a ){
        if( cells[index].equals( a );  ) cells[index] = a;
    };
};
```

where assume that `T` should be something like

```
class Point2D : public Comparable {
    public:
    virtual bool equals( Object o ){    Point2D p = (Point2D)o;     return ( ix == p.ix ) && ( iy == p.iy );    };
};
```

which a subtype of some more general type ( in Java I would use interface )

```
class Comparable {
    public:
    virtual bool equals( Object o ){ return false; };
};
```

I guess I'm missing something very basic in concept of templates.

Comment: that `T` could be any class and not all classes has a method `T.equals( Object o )`. So how can compiler know that I will later use only classes of `Comparable` type ?

Comment: The compiler knows only when it tries to instantiate the template with a particular T and checks whether that T has the appropriate member function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a trait `is_comparable<T>` that returns true or false if `operator==` is defined for `T`. Then you can use `static_assert` to create a compile-time assertion inside your `Map` class:

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct is_comparable
    : std::false_type { };

template<class T>
struct is_comparable<T, decltype(void(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>()))>
    : std::true_type { };

template<class T>
class Map
{
    // ...
    static_assert(is_comparable<T>::value, "T must be comparable");
};
```

If you pass `Map` a type for which `operator==` is not defined, you will get a compilation error with the custom message. Like Michael said, this is how you would do it in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Forget "Object" or inherited "equals" in C++. That's a Java-ism. In C++, we do it like this:

```
 class Point2D {
   public:
     // ...
     bool operator==(const Point2D& other) const;
     // ...
 };
```

In your Map code, you can simply use `x == y` instead of `x.equals(y)`. Note that your map currently has a list of pointers, so you need to dereference he pointers to do that operation (that is, you would need to do `*xPtr == *yPtr` to compare the values that are pointed to rather than the addresses.

Comment: OK, but it should be the same - how can compiler know that operator `==` is defined for all possible parameters `T` ?

Comment: @ProkopHapala that's how templates differ from inheritance. When using templates, the compiler verifies that the template is instantiated with a type that provides all the functions that are used by the template. And hence you do not need an inheritance relationship at all.